# Longest prefix match in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have 2 tables. lets just say its records and numbers

the records.number contains a number which I want to find the longest possible associated prefix in numbers.prefix in SQL Server 2000

How would I go about doing this?

e.g.

```
records.number = '0841234567'

numbers.prefix = '084'
                 '0841'
                 '08412'
```

I would want to select 08412

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select top 1 N.Prefix
from Numbers as N
  inner join Records as R
    on R.Number like N.Prefix+'%'
order by len(N.Prefix) desc
```

**Update.**

The longest prefix for each number in `Records`.

```
select R.Number,
       (select top 1 N.Prefix
        from Numbers as N
        where R.Number like N.Prefix+'%'
        order by len(N.Prefix) desc) as Prefix
from Records as R
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/71488)

Comment: Is there a way I could do it for all the records at the same time?

Comment: Thanks a lot, This has helped me so much.