# VBA/ACE OLEDB/SQL Run-Time error -2147217913 Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: sql, vba, oledb

I am running a SQL query from VBA using ACE OLEDB without connecting to Access. I do this so I can smash together quickly some Excel tables. I am not looking to transition this to another platform so would prefer to resolve the current issue.

VBA code works without issue for numerous queries but I am running into the mentioned error for the following query:

```
SELECT
    bcr.DialCode,
    bcr.Destination,
    (
        SELECT
            TOP 1 cc.CountryCode
        FROM
            table2 AS cc
        WHERE
            bcr.DialCode LIKE cc.CountryCode+'%'
        ORDER BY LEN(cc.CountryCode) DESC
    ) AS CountryCodes
FROM
    table1 AS bcr
```

Code adapted from: [Longest prefix match in SQL Server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845035/longest-prefix-match-in-sql-server-2000)

The intention is to match dialed telephone numbers to the destination country by finding the most inclusive match. Reusing the quoted text sample of input and expected results (adapted to this exercise):

```
bcr.DialCode = '0841234567'

cc.CountryCode = {'084',
                 '0841',
                 '08412'}

Expected output = {'0841234567','Destination 1','08412'}
```

From searching online seems like maybe I'm using a reserved word in the query. But I have tested different parts of the query individually and don't get any errors. For example:

```
SELECT
    bcr.DialCode,
    bcr.Destination
FROM
    table1 AS bcr
```

Works as expected. Also:

```
SELECT
    TOP 1 cc.CountryCode
FROM
    table2 AS cc
WHERE
    cc.CountryCode LIKE '1'+'%'
ORDER BY LEN(cc.CountryCode) DESC
```

Has no errors and outputs the expected results.

The variable used to pass the query to the ADO connection is dimmed as String but I have tried setting as Variant with no change.

Is there perhaps a difference in the implementation of SQL through ACE for which the "Longest prefix match" query doesn't work? Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the subquery `bcr.DialCode LIKE cc.CountryCode+'%'` I think they need to be the other way around ? and try using * as your wildcard.

Comment: ACE/OleDb database engine does not know [%]. You have to replace it with [*].

Comment: Thanks for the indications. The query does work though with `cc.CountryCode LIKE '1'+'%'` as per above (third query provided). And it outputs all the country codes that start with `1` and have the max LEN of 4. I tried changing `%` for `*` and `[*]` with the same error. Tried repacing `'%'` with `[*]` and got "No value given for one or more required parameters." Any other thoughts?

Comment: Please, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please read my comment to the question.

Secondly, please read these articles:

[I get a message about data type mismatch](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/I-get-a-message-about-data-type-mismatch-c75b62ff-bcfd-4bb0-83f8-8129f372d59f)

[MS Access 2003: LIKE condition (using wildcards)](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like.php)

Finally, if you would like to compare one data to another which `StartsWith("SomeString")`, you can use something like this:

```
SELECT
    bcr.DialCode,
    bcr.Destination,
    cc.CountryCode
FROM table1 AS bcr 
    INNER JOIN table2 AS cc 
    ON cc.CountryCode = LEFT(bcr.DialCode, LEN(cc.CountryCode))
ORDER BY LEN(cc.CountryCode) DESC;
```

For further details, please see: [MS Access: Left Function](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/left.php)

Note: Do not forget to use [`;`] at the end of query. MS Access database likes it ;)

Comment: Thank you for your further response. Using the code you provided I get a "At most one record can be returned by this subquery." error. It should produce as many matches as rows in Table1 as all calls will match to at least 1 country. Is this even considered an actual LEFT JOIN? Should I perhaps change it into using a LEFT JOIN rather then the solution that I am following?

Comment: @nbayly, check updated answer. This should return all data where `CountryCode` starts with `DialCode`. Good luck!

Comment: This is now running without errors but there are some issues with the logic of the query that I hope you can help with. It is not outputting the most inclusive match. For example for a dial code of '7708' it is matching to Russia dial code '7' rather than the more inclusive '77' Kazakhstan. Any suggestions? I am marking your answer as correct as it did resolve the run time error.

Comment: @nbayly, sorry, but not getting you... If `CountryCode` is `7` then above query should match `DialCode`s which starts with `7`. So, it should return {`7`, `70`, `717`, `7771`, etc.}

Comment: If the dial code is '7708' it should return the most inclusive matched country code between '7' (Russia) and '77' (Kazakhstan) which in this case would be '77' as more left digits of the dial code match. I hope this clarifies your doubt.

Comment: Actually I have progressed a bit but still have some issues with the results. I will post this as another question as it does not relate to my initial issue reported. Cheers

Comment: @nbayly, You can MAX() function with `WHERE` clause, for example: `WHERE MAX(LEN(cc.CountryCode)) GROUP BY bcr.DialCode,
    bcr.Destination`

Comment: I have moved the rest of my questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44295290/left-join-on-longest-match Thanks again for all your help. Regards