# Left Join on Longest Match

Tags: sql, vba, oledb

As context I am running a SQL query in VBA using ACE OLEDB.

The intent of the query is to match dial codes with their destination country. The difficulty is that the match is done not on all digits but to the country code that has the most left matching digits. For example for dial code '7708' it should match to country code '77' (Kazakhstan) but my current code also pulls in '7' (Russia) to the results.

Current query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    TRIM(STR(bcr.DialCode)) as DialCode,
    bcr.Destination,
    TRIM(STR(cc.CountryCode)) as CountryCode
FROM table1 AS bcr 
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT CountryCode
        FROM table2
        ORDER BY LEN(CountryCode) DESC
    ) AS cc 
ON cc.CountryCode = LEFT(bcr.DialCode, LEN(cc.CountryCode))
ORDER BY LEN(cc.CountryCode) DESC;
```

Mock up of schema and query here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/679084/left-join-on-longest-match . I had to remove the 'ORDER BY' as it would not accept this command. Don't think it changed the results though. Also had to change TRIM to LTRIM.

As you can see on the results, it doubles each Table1 row for '7' and '77' in the results. Would want only '77' for that particular sample of dial codes. Any guidance is much appreciated. Regards,

Comment: Not sure what you mean about delimiting for the country code. Do you mean to have another field in Table1 that has the country codes? Sadly I don't have control over this output.

Comment: That requires knowing for each dial code what the country code is before hand. Seems kinda suggesting to put the cart in front of the horse? The intent of the query is actually to find the country codes that relate to each dial code. I cannot change the structure of Table1. I can change Table2 if required though doesn't seem like it would add anything. Anything you can suggest in regards to the query itself?

Comment: From my example '7708', first try to find a match with the 4 digits. If no match drop a digit and repeat. Go until a match is found from the country codes list. In this case first match would be '77', before it would match '7', hence that should be the country code ('77') for this dial code.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your solution from data.stackexchange with following things:

- added length of country code
- changed join condition to `LIKE` matching the pattern
- added `row_number` function to properly assign the priority of length matching
- added another select statement level to choose those with longest match `rn = 1`

---

Here's the modified query:

```
SELECT DialCode, Destination, CountryCode
FROM (
  SELECT
      STR(bcr.DialCode) as DialCode,
      bcr.Destination,
      LTRIM(STR(cc.CountryCode)) as CountryCode,
      row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY bcr.DialCode ORDER BY cc.cc_len DESC) AS rn
  FROM @Table1 AS bcr 
  LEFT JOIN
      (
      SELECT CountryCode, LEN(CountryCode) AS cc_len
      FROM @Table2
      ) AS cc 
      ON bcr.DialCode LIKE CONCAT(cc.CountryCode, '%')
    ) x
WHERE rn = 1
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works as required in SO Data Explorer but fails through VBA/ACE OLEDB with error "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY bcr.DialCode ORDER BY cc.cc_len DESC)'." Any suggestion to resolve?

Comment: Searching online seems that ACE OLEDB/Access don't support 'ROW_NUMBER' function. Thanks for your efforts though.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
TOP 1 TRIM(STR(bcr.DialCode)) as DialCode,
bcr.Destination,
TRIM(STR(cc.CountryCode)) as CountryCode
FROM table1 AS bcr 
INNER JOIN table2 AS cc
ON cc.CountryCode = LEFT(bcr.DialCode, LEN(cc.CountryCode))
WHERE LEN(cc.CountryCode) = MAX(LEN(cc.CountryCode));
```

Comment: Errors out in SO Data Explorer with "Column '@Table2.CountryCode' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." Also errors in VBA/ACE OLEDB with error "Your query does not include the specified expression 'TRIM(STR(bcr.DialCode))' as part of an aggregate function." Any suggestions to resolve?

Comment: try with where instead of having. btw why do you need trim(str())?

Comment: I did try 'WHERE' as one of my random flailings but that produced an error as well. The ACE OLEDB implementaion of SQL turned out a bit trickier than I thought. I managed to solve the issue though by rewritting the query. I just pulled all the matches in a subquery, sort by LEN(cc.CountryCode) and then group all the rows but only keep LAST(t.CountryCode). I did the trim as for some reason when converting to string it was adding a blank space in front. Not sure why. Thanks for your help. Regards

Comment: you should post your solution as an answer and accept it :)